# Term frequency table to DocumentTermMatrix in tm R package

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, word-frequency

I am using the tm package in R to do some text mining. I have a matrix of term frequencies where every row is a document, every column is a word and every cell is the frequency of the word. I am trying to convert that to a `DocumentTermTermMatrix` object. I can't seem to find a function that deals with that. Looks like the sources are usually the documents.

I've tried `as.DocumentTermTermMatrix()` but it asks for an argument "weighting" giving the following error:

> Error in .TermDocumentMatrix(t(x), weighting) : 
>         argument "weighting" is missing, with no default

here is the code for a simple reproducible example

```
docs = matrix(sample(1:10, 50, replace=T), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 5, nrow=10) 
rownames(docs) = paste0("doc", 1:10)
colnames(docs) = c("grad", "school", "is", "sleep", "deprivation")
```

so I would need to coerce the matrix docs into a `DocumentTermMatrix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code example, you can use the following:

```
docs = matrix(sample(1:10, 50, replace=T), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 5, nrow=10) 
rownames(docs) = paste0("doc", 1:10)
colnames(docs) = c("grad", "school", "is", "sleep", "deprivation")

dtm <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(docs, weighting = weightTfIdf)
```

If you read the help DocumentTermMatrix you see the following under arguments

> **weighting:** A weighting function capable of handling a TermDocumentMatrix. It defaults to weightTf for term frequency
>   weighting. Available weighting functions shipped with the tm package
>   are weightTf, weightTfIdf, weightBin, and weightSMART.

Depending on your need you have to specify the weighting formula to use with your document term matrix. Or create one yourself.